# Unable to Open VF Page using PageReference for given URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, custom-url

I have called NextStep() on Button Click where I wanted to open a standard VF page provided by SF with some new additional parameters in URL - where my string **MergeURL** is just fine, but it gets changed when I try to open that URL using PageReference !!

**Apex Code :**

```
  public PageReference NextStep(){
   -----Some Code ----------
   System.Debug('----URL--'+MergeURL);   //****** THIS PRINTS THE URL CORRECT WHICH I Want to open 
   PageReference mergePage = new PageReference(MergeURL);
   mergePage.setRedirect(true);
   return mergePage;
}
```

**Debug Log :**

> ----URL--/some/some.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=00190000012UXZiAAO&cid=00190000012UWRpAAO
>
> 02:16:27.093 (93221171)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[24]|System.debug(ANY)
>   02:16:27.093
>   (93234760)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[26]|MyController.__sfdc_MergeURL()
>   02:16:27.093
>   (93248291)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[26]|MyReference.setRedirect(Boolean)
>   02:16:27.093
>   (93384265)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[27]|System.PageReference.setRedirect(Boolean)
>   02:16:27.093 (93416963)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 02:16:27.093
>   (93458930)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|MyController invoke(NextStep)
>   02:16:27.093
>   (93537389)**|VF_APEX_CALL|j_id4|{!NextStep}|PageReference:/some/some.jsp?cid=00190000012UXZiAAO&goNext=+Next+**
>   02:16:27.347 (95579984)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE

Any Suggestions !!!

Comment: What standard page is that? This sounds too hackish to me. Even if you get it work it could break anytime if Salesforce decides to change that page.

Comment: In your url both parameters are called cid and so, probably, the duplicate is removed. What happens if you call the second one something else?

Comment: I am calling  merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=SOMEID &cid=SOMEID

Comment: I think Javascript could be the solutions, but I am unaware of it !

Comment: @RichardDurrant : I have to call "cid" only since I wanted to open all those records on next page, I cant use anything else. Yes PageReference is removing duplicates, so is there any other way i can do it,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution finally by trying too many ways -

**VF Page :**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="redirect">
    <script>       
            url = '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(MergeURL)}';            
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = url;
            var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue;
            window.parent.location.href = decoded;            
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

on my Button Click where I am calling NextStep(), I rendered "redirect" which is above panels id. And It worked as I required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the `PageReference` object is going to allow you to have multiple identical parameters. Your best bet is to open the url in Javascript, like so:

```
onclick="window.location='/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid={!acct1.Id} &cid={!acct1.Id}'"
```

Instead of having an `apex:commandButton` use an `<input type="button">` with the `onclick` code above as an attribute.